# Update Table angularJS after add item using not work in view

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I use angular and angular-material for design so i can push item to array but not update in view

My code :

```
   ClientService.saveClient(client).$promise.then(
                    function(data) {
                        items.data.push(data);
                    },function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

and in $mdDialog.show my code :

```
 $scope.addClient = function (event) {
                $mdDialog.show({
                    controller: DialogController,
                    locals: {
                        items: $scope.clients
                    },
                    parent: angular.element(document.body),
                    templateUrl: 'views/client/addclient.html',
                    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                    clickOutsideToClose:true,
                    targetEvent: event
                }).then(function (add) {
                        init();
                        console.log($scope.clients);
                }, function(cancel) {
                });
            };
```

In console log the client added with success but not update in table .

ps init function :

```
 var init = function () {
            ClientService.getClients().$promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.clients = {
                    "count":data.length,
                    "data":data
                };
            });
        };
```

So how can i get client after added ? and thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
ClientService.getClients().$promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.clients = {
                    "count":data.length,
                    "data":data
                };
        $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: try this $timeout(function() {
  $scope.$apply();
})

Comment: what ispassword  ?